# Euler #3 largest prime factor

Tags: c, programming-challenge, primes, time-limit-exceeded

**Problem Statement**

This problem is a programming version of Problem 3 from projecteuler.net

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of a given number N?
>
> Input Format First line contains T, the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines each containing an integer N.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each test case, display the largest prime factor of N.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> \$1 \le T \le 10\$
>
> \$10 \le N \le 10^{12}\$

```
#include<stdio.h>  //C language
int main()
{
long long  number; //Declaring Variables 
int cases;
scanf("%d",&cases);
while(cases--)
{
    scanf("%lld",&number);
    long long div=2, ans = 0, maxFact;
    while(number!=0)
        {
            if(number % div !=0)
                div = div + 1;
            else
            {
                maxFact  = number;
                number = number / div;

                if(number == 1)
                    {
                        printf("%lld\n",maxFact);
                        ans = 1;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

How can the speed be increased? This code gives me timeout error in the last test case of HackerRank.

Answer (score 14):

### Use properties of prime numbers

The only prime number that is even is 2, for the simple reason that if the number is even, it is evenly divisible by 2 and is thus not a prime.

So after checking if 2 is a factor and removing it, simply start with `div = 3`  and in the update do `div = div + 2`. And you're twice as fast!

But there is more, consider \$x=6k+l\$ where \$l\in\left[0,5\right]\in \mathcal{Z}\$ and \$k\ge 0\$. It's obvious \$x\$ can represent any positive integer.

Assume for a second that \$k>0\$ and let's look a bit closer:

- \$x=6k+0\$  is always be divisible by 2 and 3.
- \$x=6k+1\$ This might be a prime (7, 13 for example are primes).
- \$x=6k+2=2\cdot (3k+1)\$ is always divisible by 2.
- \$x=6k+3=3\cdot (2k+1)\$ is always divisible by 3.
- \$x=6k+4=2\cdot(3k+2)\$  is always divisible by 2.
- \$x=6k+5\$ This might be a prime (11, 19 for example are primes).

Now note that \$6k+5 = 6\left(k+1\right)-1\$ so after checking the divisors we would miss at the start (2 and 3) set `div=6` and try division with `div-1` and `div+1` then increase `div` by six and repeat.

This means that you're skipping 2/3rds of all divisors, i.e. ~300% faster.

### Your exit condition for the loop is useless

As the input is guaranteed larger than zero, `number!=0` will always be true in your loop condition. In fact you can reduce branching even further like this:

```
while(number!=1){
    while(number % div == 0){
        number = number / div;
        maxFact = div;
    }
    div = div + 1;
}
printf("%lld\n",maxFact);
ans = 1;
```

that's one branch less per iteration.

Answer (score 11):

On top of the answer by [Emily L.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90503/73402) you can add a simple primality test as an exit condition for the loop, this will also avoid a lot of iterations.

```
while(number!=1 && div <= sqrt(number))
```

Where `sqrt(number)` is the square root of the number in each iteration.

If \$ n \$ does not have divisors \$ < \sqrt{n} \$, then  \$ n \$ is prime and thus you can stop looking for larger prime factors and output \$n\$.

Comment: The square root idea is good in mathematical principle, but can fail due to precision of the types involved.  `number` precision may exceed the `double` of `sqrt()`.  Better to use a matching `sqrt_same_type_as_number()` or other tricks (look at quotient) to insure  `div <= sqrt(number)` does not "just miss".

Answer (score 8):

### Don't iterate all the way until N

Your current worst case scenario is when `number` is a very large prime number.  When this happens you will try every `div` from 2 to `number`.  Although skipping even numbers or even 2/3 of the numbers (as suggested by Emily L) will increase your speed by 2x or 3x, you still have to iterate N/3 times which can take a long time.

To avoid this, you should compute `Math.sqrt(number)` at the start and recompute it whenever `number` decreases.  Whenever `div` goes above the sqrt, you know that the remaining `number` is the last prime factor.  This turns the \$O(N)\$ algorithm into an \$O(\sqrt N)\$ algorithm.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something! Let that be a lesson kids, don't do code reviews before your morning coffee! ;)

Answer (score 3):

The better result I've obtained is using the function below (`lpf5()`). It's based on the `primality()` function (below) that uses the formulas 6k+1, 6k-1 to individuate prime numbers. All prime numbers >= 5 may be expressed in one of the forms `p=k*6+1` or `p=k*6-1` with k>0 (but not all the numbers having such a forms are primes). Developing these formulas we can see a sequence like the following:

```
k=1 5,7
k=2 11,13
k=3 17,19
k=4 23,25*
k=5 29,31
.
.
.
k=10 59,61
k=11 65*,67
k=12 71,73
...

5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,...,59,61,65,67,71,73,...
```

We observe that the difference between the terms is alternatively 2 and 4. Such a results may be obtained also using simple math. Is obvious that the difference between k*6+1 and k*6-1 is 2. It's simple to note that the difference between k*6+1 and (k+1)*6-1 is 4.

The function `primality(x)` returns x when x is prime (or 0 - take care) and the first divisor occurs when x is not prime.

I think you may obtain a better result inlining the `primality()` function inside the `lpf5()` function.

I've also tried to insert a table with some primes (from 1 to 383 - the primes in the first 128 results of the indicated formulas) inside the primality function, but the speed difference is unappreciable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef  long long unsigned int uint64;
uint64 lpf5(uint64 x);
uint64 primality(uint64 x);

uint64 lpf5(uint64 x)
{
    uint64 x_=x;

    while ( (x_=primality(x))!=x)
        x=x/x_;

    return x;
}

uint64 primality(uint64 x)
{
    uint64 div=7,f=2,q;

    if (x<4 || x==5)
        return x;

    if (!(x&1))
        return 2;

    if (!(x%3))
        return 3;

    if (!(x%5))
        return 5;

    q=sqrt(x);
    while(div<=q) {
        if (!(x%div)) {
            return div;
        }
        f=6-f;
        div+=f;
    }

    return x;
}

int main(void) {
    uint64 x,k;

    do {
        printf("Input long int: ");
        if (scanf("%llu",&x)<1)
            break;

        printf("Largest Prime Factor: %llu\n",lpf5(x));
    } while(x!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code based on [Emily L](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/36120/emily-l)'s logic. It works and solves all test cases, but I am not very pleased with how long it is.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int T,i,np;
    unsigned long long N,div,lpf,maxN;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++){
        scanf("%llu",&N);
        lpf=N;
        while(N%2==0 && N!=1 ){
            N/=2;
            lpf = N;
        }
        if (N==1) lpf=2;
        else{
            while(N%3==0 && N!=1 ){
                N/=3;
                lpf = N;
            }
            if (N==1)lpf=3;
            else{
                for (div=6;(div-1)<=sqrt(N)+1;div+=6){
                    while((N%(div-1))==0 && N!=1){
                        N/=(div-1);
                        if (N==1)lpf=(div-1);
                        else lpf=N;
                    }
                    while((N%(div+1))==0 && N!=1){
                        N/=(div+1);
                        if (N==1)lpf=(div+1);
                        else lpf=N;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%llu\n",lpf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```