# General primality test in C++

Tags: c++, performance, primes

I have this code, which I think can be optimized even more, but I can't think of a way of optimizing the main loop to make it faster and more comprehesive. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

template <class Integral>
bool IsPrime (const Integral &n){
   // Get rid of base cases
   if (n==2 || n==3) return true;

   // Initialize the boolean to an intuitive correct value
   bool is_prime = n%2 != 0 && n%3 != 0;
   unsigned long top = (unsigned long) sqrt(n)+1;

   // This is the loop I want to optimize
   for (unsigned long i=3; i<top && is_prime; i+=6){
      is_prime = (n%(i+2) != 0) && (n%(i+4) != 0);  // kind of loop unrolling...
   }

   return is_prime;
}

// Main program
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
   // Check passed arguments
   if (argc != 2){
      std::cerr << "Format: " << argv[0] << " <integer>" << std::endl;
      return -1;
   }

   if (IsPrime(strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0))) return 0;
   else return 1;
}
```

As you can see, I could reduce the amount of iterations by six times, but going further was worthless.

For the biggest 64-bit unsigned prime number, 18446744073709551557, it spends about 15-17 seconds in an i5, 1.70 GHz processor (which I think can be optimized more).

Comment: I don't remember the speed of this primality test, but it seemed me good. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90492/euler-3-largest-prime-factor/91189#91189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simple errors

This code includes `<cmath>` and `<cstdlib>`, but then calls unqualified `sqrt` and `strtoul`.  Implementations are not required to import these names to the global namespace, so they should be qualified with `std::` (or include `<math.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` instead).

An `unsigned long` may not be big enough to hold the integer part of `sqrt(n)` (for example, if `Integer` is a 128-bit type, and `unsigned long` is only 32 bits).  The only safe way (short of heavy template metaprogramming) is to use `Integer` for the counter.

It's probably worth explicitly returning false for 0 and 1, and for any negative values that crazy people feel compelled to test.

### Style

We usually use `snake_case` (or in some projects, `camelCase`) for functions, and reserve `PascalCase` for composite types.  But go along with the conventions of your collaborators where necessary.

### Performance

I did manage to get a small improvement (from 9½ seconds down to about 9 here, compiled with `gcc -march=native -03`) by splitting the condition into two (I think this might be allowing the compiler to execute both tests together).

The best results were obtained by simply parallelizing the algorithm (`std::atomic<bool>` is quite cheap on my hardware):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class Integral>
bool is_prime(const Integral &n){
    // Get rid of base cases
    if (n < 2) return false;
    if (n==2 || n==3) return true;

    if (n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false;

    auto const top = (Integral)std::sqrt(n) + 1;
    std::atomic<bool> is_prime = true;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (Integral i = 3;  i < top;  i += 6) {
        if (!is_prime) continue;
        if (n%(i+2) == 0) is_prime = false;
        if (n%(i+4) == 0) is_prime = false;
    }
    return is_prime;
}

#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    // Check passed arguments
    if (argc != 2){
        std::cerr << "Format: " << argv[0] << " <integer>" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (is_prime(std::strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0))) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

This got my time down to under 1½ seconds elapsed time, making full use of 8 cores.

I don't know how I can `break` instead of `continue` in an OpenMP parallel loop, but I found it didn't hurt too much with a simple composite number such as 625, which evaluated in around 20ms.

### Loop unrolling

I did gain a speedup of a further 20% or so by unrolling the loop to consider 30 factors at a time:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <initializer_list>

template<class Integral>
bool is_prime(const Integral &n)
{
    // Values under 30
    if (n < 2) return false;
    for (Integral i: { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 })
        if (n%i == 0) return n==i;

    auto const top = (Integral)std::sqrt(n) + 1;
    std::atomic<bool> is_prime = true;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (Integral i = 30;  i < top;  i += 30) {
        if (!is_prime) continue;
        if (n%(i+1) == 0) is_prime = false;
        if (n%(i+7) == 0) is_prime = false;
        if (n%(i+11) == 0) is_prime = false;
        if (n%(i+13) == 0) is_prime = false;
        if (n%(i+17) == 0) is_prime = false;
        if (n%(i+19) == 0) is_prime = false;
        if (n%(i+23) == 0) is_prime = false;
        if (n%(i+29) == 0) is_prime = false;
    }
    return is_prime;
}

int main()
{
    return is_prime(0)
        || is_prime(1)
        || !is_prime(2)
        || is_prime(49)
        || is_prime(961)
        || !is_prime(18446744073709551557u);
}
```

(I've also simplified `main()` here, to just run auto tests rather than requiring an argument).

Comment: 1. I didn't know that c libraries required std:: namespace, which I'm really glad to know.
2. The point of using templates was so any kind of Integral can be checked, but I forgot to do the same inside the function.
3. The return of 0 or 1 is for bash condition statements.
4. I've never heard about the `-march=` option and when to use it. Also, I usually don't use -O3 (always -O2).
5. I considered parallelizing the algorithm, but I wanted to go as far as I could using a single thread.
6. I thought of a different way of unrolling the loop, but yours works as well.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that you must use `-O3` - I noted that only to be clear how I tested.  [`-march=native`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options#index-march-12) can be very useful - it tells the compiler to generate the best code it can for the processor on which we're compiling, but which might not run elsewhere.  `-mtune=native` is similar, but the code will at least run on other versions of the processor (possibly not as quickly).

Comment: I wasn't sure whether you'd considered parallelising the the test, so I looked for improvements in single-threaded and parallel execution - I hope it was helpful to you.

Comment: I now assume that the `-march` option stands for "machine architecture", which sound really useful for personal use, I really appreciate that! Thank you very much for your answer, I didn't thought I would have learnt that much in a single post.

Answer (score 0):

To my eye, you can make some improvements when looking at base cases:

```
bool IsPrime (const Integral &n){

  // Get rid of base cases.
  if (n <= 1) {
    return false;
  }

  // Handle even numbers.
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return n == 2;
  }  

  // Handle multiples of 3.
  if (n % 3 == 0) {
    return n == 3;
  }

  // ...
```

That diverts all multiples of 2 and 3 before you have to set up your loop only not to run it: `&& is_prime`.  I also find it easier to read, though YMMV.

Your loop unrolling is a bit strange to my eye.  You start at 3, which you have already checked for, instead of 5 and have to compensate in every repetition of your loop.  Checking that `&& is_prime` every time seems unnecessary as you can `return false;` as soon as any divisor is found.

```
for (unsigned long i = 5; i < top; i += 6) {
  if ((n % i != 0) || (n % (i + 2) != 0) {
    return false;
  }
}

// If we get here then the number is prime.
return true;
```

I haven't run any timings, but this has a simplified end-of-loop check and one less addition per loop so it might shave a little off the time.